# how to remote into 16.04 via rdp

Tags: rdp, xrdp, 16.04

All available information is for ancient versions, so here specifically for 16.04:

Is it possible to remote in via a MSWindows PC with mstsc.exe to a Ubuntu 16.04 PC running xrdp **without the need to install an alternate desktop?**

This is broken since 12.04, so any update here would be appreciated.

Comment: @DnrDevil: 16.04 is feature frozen since Feb 25. There is no reason why the question can't be asked now. The results won't change in April

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/872/332437 is the official stance from askubuntu meta regarding ubuntu+1 questions. Mine is clearly a valid one, asking about features coming up. Too bad it has gotten no interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated information**

It's possible to use XRDP IN conjunction with Unity Desktop in Ubuntu 16.04....Please read full instruction at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962
You will basically need to perform the following actions

- install tigervnc
- install xrdp
- modify the.xsession file

and you are good to go....

If you are still using the vnc4server or x11vncserver, you can also use a quick and dirty workaround (explained [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956)) .  Basically, you will install a vncserver on your Ubuntu machine and the xrdp package software.  When connecting to your ubuntu machine via the remote desktop,  you will select the connect to console option and you will see your Unity Desktop.  In this case, you basically using the xRDP as a proxy server that allows you to access your desktop through VNC protocol

Note : Some people mentioned that there might be a need to check firewall status.  If firewall software is running on the Ubuntu machine where xRDP is installed, you might need to open the appropriate ports (i.e. 3389)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. I know your c-nergy.be website for years, and it was always a good guide for xrdp on linux for me. My issue is that I want a good remote experience, without having to install a shitton of unneeded things.

Your quick-and-dirty solution is just bolting vnc on top of rdp, and vnc is laggy and frustrating to use, even with just a local LAN.

For alternatives, you favour MATE, but is also pulls in at least 200 MB. Is there nothing smaller which keeps at least the graphic experience?

XFCE, LXQt, MATE all are bulky.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, with the exception that it wouldn't connect until I opened port 3389 on the Ubuntu box. Strange that that not only wasn't mentioned anywhere, but none of the 100 comments mentioned it either. It's not possible that I'm the only one running a firewall, is it?

Comment: The guide also fails to mention that sessman-vnc must be selected. Is there a reason 16.xx is so finicky about this? I ended up installing a ton of stuff just to finally succeed with VNC.

Comment: We will try to take into accounts these comments and improve the answers... Thank you for the feedback