# how do I RDP to Ubuntu 16.04 from windows

Tags: 16.04, rdp

how do I RDP to Ubuntu 16.04 from windows?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate of a few other posts. You can use xRDP to rdp into your linux workstation. If you are looking to use rdp and log in to a Unity desktop, perform the following:

1. Install TigerVNC
2. Install xRDP
3. Configure preferred desktop to be used in xRDP

Full Instructions on how to perform this can be found at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962

Also see [How to use xrdp with Unity on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760198/how-to-use-xrdp-with-unity-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)